# Issue with video in a CarouselView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

Hey so I've set up a CarouselView with a video in each cell

```
   <CarouselView
    x:Name="TheCarousel">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                                <video:VideoPlayer Source="{Binding Uri}" HeightRequest="480"/>
                             </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
           
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

It is working, the videos play, however when i scroll to a different video, the previous one plays by itself. For example, if i pause the first video, then scroll over to the second video, the first video will start playing. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which videoplayer you use, but I use **Octane.Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer**, don't have this problem.

```
 <CarouselView x:Name="TheCarousel" ItemsSource="{Binding videos}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Label
                            FontSize="Title"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding title}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <o:VideoPlayer
                            AutoPlay="True"
                            DisplayControls="True"
                            FillMode="ResizeAspectFill"
                            Source="{Binding path}" />

                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>

 public partial class Page5 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<videomodel> videos { get; set; }
    public Page5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        videos = new ObservableCollection<videomodel>()
        {
              new videomodel(){path="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/a7e9/abda3d53-bed3-4f20-9f53-70047a35a7e9/Xamarin101WhatIsXamarin_high.mp4",title="title 2"},
              new videomodel(){path="https://ia800201.us.archive.org/12/items/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4",title="title 1"},
          
              new videomodel(){path="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/3901/c6e0e4e6-bb93-4033-a484-040a874f3901/Xamarin101XamarinFormsMVVMXAML_high.mp4",title="title 3"}                
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;

    }
}

public class videomodel
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

}